# Google Drive Java API

Tags: java, compilation, google-drive-api

I am desperately trying to compile

[Quickstart: Run a Drive App in Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java)

but no matter what, I always hit on:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient

The same thing happens both for at the servlet and the SE version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The code compiled and ran fine here.

### Steps:

- Create/select a project at [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) , enable the Drive API, create a new Client ID so that you have a valid `CLIENT_ID`,`CLIENT_SECRET`,`REDIRECT_URI`.
- Download `google-api-services-drive-v2-rev123-java-1.18.0-rc.zip`, extract it and put the following jars in your classpath.

[image]

- Create a text file `document.txt` and put it in the same package(assuming you are using eclipse as IDE) as your source code.
- Provide the generated CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,REDIRECT_URI(Step 1) in your source code.
- Compile and run the code.

### Output:

[image]

Copy the code provided in the browser, paste it in console.

The document will be uploaded to your Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had to use the suitable Drive API from [Drive API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2)