# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a text file to my Google Drive account. No matter what, I always encounter an `com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden`

### Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at chatterjee.sandeep.javabase.miscellaneous.DriveCommandLine.main(DriveCommandLine.java:69)
```

Here is line 69 of `DriveCommandLine.java`

```
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

### Complete Code:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DriveCommandLine {

    private static String CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";
    private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET";

    private static String REDIRECT_URI = "REDIRECT_URI";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
        Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)).setAccessType("online")
        .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

        String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
        .build();
        System.out
        .println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
        System.out.println("  " + url);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = br.readLine();

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code)
        .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential()
        .setFromTokenResponse(response);

        // Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
        credential).build();

        // Insert a file
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("My document");
        body.setDescription("A test document");
        body.setMimeType("text/plain");

        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(
        "/path/to/TextFile.txt");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
    }
}
```

I have the following jars in my project build path:

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-java6-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-services-drive-v1-rev123-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-java6-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-jetty-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar
gson-2.1.jar
httpclient-4.0.3.jar
httpcore-4.0.1_1.jar
jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
transaction-api-1.1-rev-1.jar
```

At present I have two projects set up with Drive API enabled.

[image]

Now where do I properly set up the permissions to resolve this issue?

Also, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471741/code-403-and-reason-forbidden-exception-at-uploading-file-in-google-p

Comment: @RenuThakur I went through the SO post suggested by you. The OP on that post seems to be using [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/?hl=en_US) and
not [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/?hl=en_US). Also, it seems, he is using Android smartphone to upload files which is not my case.

Comment: I forgot to add that [when I tried running the code an year back, it ran fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613317/google-drive-java-api/23616857#23616857). The `Quickstart: Run a Drive App in Java` mentioned by the OP in that [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613317/google-drive-java-api/23616857) has been changed/updated since. For some reason, it is
throwing an `com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException` now. I would like to know why is it so.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, I did the following change and it resolved the issue

1) Added SheetsScopes.DRIVE to the scopes to be given in authorize()

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS,SheetsScopes.DRIVE);
```

2) Created a new directory, so that next time I run it, it will authenticate and save the credential to the newly created directory

```
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/2/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json");
```

Comment: ^this.
The DATA_STORE_DIR is an argument for FileDataStoreFactory. If you had already been working with another google API, e.g., sheets, you need to overwrite the credentials file in the data_store

Answer (score 6):

This issue happened when you change SCOPE and proceed to work with the old token. Just remove StoredCredential file.[Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1OtD.png)

Answer (score 4):

After a long time searching, I found this answer hidden in the search engine:

Change the line where you define scopes to:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38599382/1317559

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem and it is likely that you have created the credential file using a scope that does not allow inserting a file. Remove the credential file and re-run.

Answer (score 2):

For me issue was **SCOPES**, it was set to **SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY**.

So I changed it to **SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS**, deleted the Token folder in the project directory and run the program again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Been having same quota errors for months. Tried everything. It looks like problem on Google side.
Among all google products, Calendar API does not have any way to support their team. If anyone knows or have been able to contact Google team about Calendar API, let us know!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but in my case resolve this with:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```

from [DriveScopes](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/DriveScopes.html)

and also create a new directory

```
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/2/drive-java-quickstart.json");
```

and i solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the url was http... and it should be https...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to use DriveScopes.DRIVE for allowed SCOPE:
   private static final List SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
2. Make sure to reset token directory path as below:

   ```
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT,
            JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            //.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setDataStoreFactory(new MemoryDataStoreFactory())
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
   ```

Othewise it will always use the cached version.