# Gmail-API JAVA Client Send Email Insufficient Permission

Tags: java, email, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I am trying to send email by Gmail. I nearly grant all scope to the service. But I still got the error message, insufficient permission.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}

    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at GmailQuickstart.main(GmailQuickstart.java:133)
```

:run FAILED

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS, GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE, GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT, GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY, GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY, GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
        GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}
```

Comment: If modifying scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.

Comment: That is the below answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to delete C:\Users\user.credentials
Because I run for many times. For first times, I did not grant the full right.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this answer. It should answer your question. I cannot post the answer here because it is illegal to post a duplicate. This worked for me. Found this after a long time of searching. Let me know if it worked for you too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639526/1317559

Answer (score 0):

Delete `C:\Users\user.credentials` and change your scopes according to what you need.

```
SCOPES = Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS, GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT, GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the SCOPE from SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY to SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS.

private static final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

```
//private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
```