# add signature of gmail using gmail API

Tags: java, rest, google-api, gmail-api

I am new to Gmail APIs. I need to add a signature using google APIs via java.

I followed & tried https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java and working fine.

But, when I am integrating tis code into the above link code. 403 error it's throwing.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
            "Gmail API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/gmail-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/gmail-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);


    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
                Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Gmail client service.
     * @return an authorized Gmail client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Gmail getGmailService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Gmail service = getGmailService();
        String user = "me";

        ListLabelsResponse listResponse =
                service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        //        SendAs primaryAlias = null;
        //      ListSendAsResponse aliases = service.users().settings().sendAs().list("me").execute();
        //        for (SendAs alias: aliases.getSendAs()) {
        //            if (alias.getIsPrimary()) {
        //                primaryAlias = alias;
        //                break;
        //            }
        //        }
        //        SendAs aliasSettings = new SendAs().setSignature("I heart cats.");
        //        SendAs result = service.users().settings().sendAs().patch(
        //                "me",
        //                primaryAlias.getSendAsEmail(),
        //                aliasSettings)
        //                .execute();
        //        System.out.println("Updated signature for " + result.getDisplayName());
        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        //ListLabelsResponse listResponse =
        //      service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
        if (labels.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No labels found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Labels:");
            for (Label label : labels) {
                System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The error I am facing is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:101)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

How can I access signature and update my signature from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experienced the same error.

Just go to the /Users/pc-name/.credentials/gmail-java-quickstart

just delete the credentials.

try using basic setting scope. you will access the settings of gmail.

Let me know if you face any problems.

Comment: Thank you so much :) . Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Managing Aliases](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings).

> Aliases are also used to manage signatures for an account.

Try the example given in the documentation.

```
SendAs primaryAlias = null;
ListSendAsResponse aliases = gmailService.users().settings().sendAs().list("me").execute();
for (SendAs alias: aliases.getSendAs()) {
    if (alias.getIsPrimary()) {
        primaryAlias = alias;
        break;
    }
}
SendAs aliasSettings = new SendAs().setSignature("I heart cats.");
SendAs result = gmailService.users().settings().sendAs().patch(
        "me",
        primaryAlias.getSendAsEmail(),
        aliasSettings)
        .execute();
System.out.println("Updated signature for " + result.getDisplayName());
```

For the errors, you can check the SO post below.

- [Gmail-API JAVA Client Send Email Insufficient Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753538/gmail-api-java-client-send-email-insufficient-permission/33754440)

Comment: Thank you . I used the same thing.. After integrating this code, 403 forbidden error throws.... I have commented this code in my question.u can check that. Please let me know if u have any suggestion