# Google Calendar API v3: Access Not Configured

Tags: android, calendar, google-api

We are working on an Android App and getting this error:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden { "code": 403, "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits",
>   "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers
>   Console to activate the API for your project.", "reason":
>   "accessNotConfigured" } ...

I have tried:

Turning on the Calendar API in the console
Filling out the Google Console consent screen
Turning on the JSON API
Deleting the debug.keystore and re-generating the SHA1 key and updating it in Google Console
Re-generating the API Key in Google Console and integrating it into the Android code in the Manifest
Doing a clean build of the Android code
What else can it be?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476746/com-google-api-client-googleapis-json-googlejsonresponseexception-403-forbidden

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863022/edit-google-calendar-events-from-google-service-account-403/11897793#11897793 https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

Comment: Turning on the Calendar API in the console  <-- check again message says you haven't done that yet.

Comment: yea i have done all the steps. Turning on calendar api, create client id etc but not working :(

Comment: Little child : in the first url the solution is not given. i checked.iN the second Url work doing for editing, right now i want to retrieve details from google calendar. please help me to solve the problem

Comment: @sucharitaganguly Have you solved this?