# Error when trying to send an email using Gmail API in Java

Tags: java, email, gmail, gmail-api

I want to send an email using Gmail API (not JavaMail). I read many similar topics on forums, but I have still a problem.

First I read this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

and I impelemented methods: MimeMessage createEmail, Message createMessageWithEmail and Message sendMessage

Then I noticed that I don't have definition of object Gmail service, so I needed a class GmailQuickstart, which is here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

and I implemented: class GmailQuickstart, method Credential authorize() and method Gmail getGmailService()

Finally I wrote a main:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    String APPLICATION_NAME = "gmailProject";
    HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    Credential credential = GmailQuickstart.authorize();

    String to = "frommail@gmail.com";
    String from = "tomail@gmail.com";
    String subject = "Subject";
    String bodyText = "Body";
    MimeMessage emailcontent = createEmail(to, from, subject, bodyText);
    createMessageWithEmail(emailcontent);
    Gmail service = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    sendMessage(service, "me", emailcontent);
}
```

After this I have a long lists of errors:

```
Exception in thread "main"com.google.api.client.googleapis. json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
  "domain" : "global",
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
  "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
} ],
"message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJs nResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at org.actuarlib.outsourcing.mail.Mail.sendMessage(Mail.java:78)
    at org.actuarlib.outsourcing.mail.Mail.main(Mail.java:195)
```

I know that on stack there are many topics about similar error, but I don't know how to correct it.
Anyone can tell me what's wrong or do you know another way to send an email using Gmail API?

Comment: Where did you provide the authorization credentials (`client_secret.json`)? The error says your credentials are missing or invalid.

Comment: This file I have in the same folder where I have my class

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you have authorized with insufficient permission. This line of code is the problem:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
```

If you check the reference for [listing labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list#auth), you will see that the permission  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels` is enough.

This is however not sufficient for [sending messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#auth). You can change your SCOPES to include `https://mail.google.com/` while developing, until you know exactly what permission you need:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
```

Comment: I changed the line you wrote, but I have the same error.

Comment: Make sure you remove your stored credentials, as those would still be using the wrong scope.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @Yster No problem :) Happy to help.